# Why using(){} block is repeatedly called in a function containing yield return?

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code. The query take some 30 seconds to execute. I found that the top `using` block is called every time `for each` try to enumerate the iterator. Which mean query is executed for each call to `MoveNext` in enumerator.

So why lazy evaluation reintialize `using` over and over again. I know the work around but i need to understand the purpose of this.

```
   private IEnumerable<FriendProfile> GetProfiles() {
        var query = @"
            SELECT VirtualNumber, City, Gender, Nick, Age
            FROM Profiles
            WHERE Not VirtualNumber  In ( SELECT VirtualNumber FROM Messages)
            ORDER BY Id DESC;";

        using (var con = GetConnection()) {
            using (var cmd = dbconnection.CreateCommand()) {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    var fp = new FriendProfile();
                    fp.VirtualNumber = reader.GetString(0);
                    fp.City = reader.GetString(1);
                    fp.Gender = reader.GetString(2);
                    fp.Nick = reader.GetString(3);
                    fp.Age = reader.GetInt16(4).ToString();
                    yield return fp;

                }
            }
        }
    }


    foreach(var fp in GetProfiles()){
    .... //foreach item using(){} in GetProfile() is reinitializes. All usings blocks
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure which using block you are referring to, but if I have understood correctly, what you have said should not be happening. The `yield` will return control of execution from the `GetProfiles()` method, but the code after the `yield` (ie. the end of the `using` blocks) will not be executed until the `while` condition is `false`.

Here is a simple example that should demonstrate this behaviour:

Using this class to show when the end of the `using` block executes:

```
public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Disposable(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing of {0}", name);
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
private IEnumerable<int> Test()
{
    using (new Disposable("outer"))
    {
        using (new Disposable("inner"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
}

...

foreach (int i in Test())
{
    Console.WriteLine("item {0}", i);
}
```

The output is:

```
item 0
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 5
item 6
item 7
item 8
item 9
disposing of inner
disposing of outer
```

This shows that the `using` blocks do not exit until the `for` loop exits.

Comment: you right i was doing a mistake. ` IEnumerable<int> a = Test();` and i was using a multiple time in multiple loops. for each it calls `a.GetEnumerator()` to iterate and thats why previous enumerator was garbage collected or dispose. i should have save `var b= Test().GetEnumerator()` and use it multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way `yield` gets compiled.  It's actually an iterative call to a class created just to implement the collection defined by your `GetProfiles()` method.  `MoveNext()` in that is called once per step through your `foreach`.  [This](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/) is a decent intro to what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Just tested it. Finally(and thus using) gets called only once. Probably when the iterator either arrives at the end or gets disposed.